# Comment Section in PHP using HTML form and MySQL database

Tags: php, html, mysql, include, comments

I'm *very* new to PHP- and am trying to teach myself a bit of web programming with hands-on learning. I've stumbled upon this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CS45YAqCgX8 video series on how to build a comment section, but am stuck.

**My First PHP file looks as such:**

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
If(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    $name=$_POST['name']; 
    $comment=$_POST['comment']; 

If(name&&comment) 
{
    $insert=mysqli_query("INSERT INTO comment (name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')");
} 
}       
/*else
echo "Please fill out your name and leave a comment.*/



?>
<html>
<br/>
<br/>
<body>
<form action = "CommentForm.php" method = "post">
<table>
<br/>
<tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type = "text" name = "name" size = "30"/></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2">Comment:</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><textarea name = "comment"></textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2"><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Comment"/></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**The connection file is:**

```
<?php
    mysqli_connect("My Host", "My Username","My Password");
    mysqli_select_db("My Database");
?>
```

**-and the HTML I want to attach it to is as such**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <title>Pokemon</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" 
           href = "stylishandviewtiful.css">
      </head>
      <body>
         <br/>
         <br/>
         <br/>
         <br/>
        <h3><a href = "Competitive Meta and Community.html">Competitive Meta and Community</a></h3>
        <h3><a href = "Game StorylinesTheoriesOverthought.html">In-Game Story Ideas and Opinions</a></h3>
      </body>
      <?php include 'CommentForm.php'; ?>
    </html>
```

I'll suppose I can't just use an include function? Would I see a better return to separate the HTML in the first PHP application into its own file?

I may generally need a tutorial for this specific instance that starts slow enough for any layman to follow.

Comment: Yes, you can include snippets using the `include()` function. Does it not work in your case? The file `CommentForm.php` will need to exist in the same folder as the file that references it.

Comment: (Your database credentials appear to be in the edit history here, so you need to change your password on the live server).

Comment: It exists in the same folder. In fact, the page I planned to test it on is here: http://kotetgames.com/Pokemon.html    I'm not sure exactly what is wrong, since the best I can do for compiling right now is trial and error. So I'm not 100% sure it is the include statement causing the problem

Comment: OK. So what's the problem? Does the snippet in this file not get included?

Comment: The Form doesn't appear at all for starters

Comment: (If you are working on a live server, transfer your files to your local machine, and work there - you can copy it back to live once it works).

Comment: What does `CommentForm.php` have in it? It's not your first file in the question, is it?

Comment: It's supposed to take information from a form, and then drop them into the database I so gracefully gave my credentials out for ><

Comment: Yes, CommentForm.php is the first file.

Comment: Right, you are including an HTML file in an HTML file, and you cannot do that. There can only be one set of `<html>` tags, one `<head>` set and one `<body>` set. Make a snippet called `CommentForm.php` containing your `<form>` and then `include` this wherever you need it.

Comment: Also, your `Pokemon.html` file is not a PHP file, it's an HTML file. If you view the source you'll see the `include()` function has not run. Rename this file to `Pokemon.php`.

Comment: I've removed the html, head, and body tags- in CommentForm.php,     but changing Pokemon.html into a php file removes a page from my web layout. I'm now trying to figure out how to retain that page

Comment: Righto. Note that, as an unrelated issue, you have SQL injection vulnerabilities in the PHP code above too. I wonder if it would help to try some general tutorials to help you to build things in the right way? I have a (quite substantial) tutorial in my profile - take a look, as it is aimed at beginners.

Comment: The tutorial sounds right up my alley. Already bookmarked- I really appreciate it :). But in the mean, as a holdover- will Pokemon.html simply not be able to work with a comment box in its current state? Changing it into a php file creates a bit of a gap in my site navigation.

Comment: Why has renaming this file caused a gap in your site navigation? Are there references to the old file name in several places around your site? If so, change them to the new name.

Comment: Pokemon.html was the webpage I linked earlier. It is referenced elsewhere on my site as an html page. I can simply change the coding in the "parent page" from ".html" to ".php" to achieve a similar result, right?

Comment: Yes, just find all the places you have referenced the old name, and change it to the new name. It _is_ possible to get PHP to process HTML files, but I think that is of an extra complexity that would not be helpful right now.

Comment: ah- ok. I get an internal server error (500) when attempting to navigate to the page entitled with a .php ending now though. Maybe I should just take a look at the tutorial and start from scratch, or is there something simple I'm missing? ><

Comment: A 500 error means that you need to check your server logs for what happened. This happens when error reporting is turned off on the server you are using, and so the report of the fault goes to a log rather than the screen.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll be checking out the tutorial in the near future to find out how to iron out kinks in my coding after I get a rudimentary version up and running. I managed to get it to inject data into my database as initially hoped thanks to the help I received from you and the commenter below. Thanks again! :D     Basically- I made sure the credentials matched my new ones, made the change suggested below, and double checked the spelling of all relevant objects.

Comment: Great. Don't forget to deal with the SQL injection issue before going live with the code that you have.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put the connection inside the mysqli_query($con,"insert ...")
otherwise your insert will be linked to $link. second try making connection like this $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db"); pass your $con to your mysqli_query

see http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

and if your form still does not appear you need to look at your include file. If there is something wrong it will abort

Comment: I was wondering how the connection file was going to work with the comment file. Taht always did seem odd to me. Thank you- it works now :D

Comment: your script does'nt load becuz it aborts at the begin. PHP loads first and if there is a error it'll abort .Thats why you did not see your form.

Comment: Is everything running well now ?